# npm error code ELIFECYCLE for postinstall bower install

Tags: node.js, git, npm

I am getting the followin error when running npm install:

```
66283 error Windows_NT 6.1.7601
66284 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
66285 error node v4.2.1
66286 error npm  v2.14.7
66287 error code ELIFECYCLE
66288 error MyProject@0.0.0 postinstall: `bower install`
66288 error Exit status 1
66289 error Failed at the MyProject@0.0.0 postinstall script 'bower install'.
66289 error This is most likely a problem with the MyProject package,
66289 error not with npm itself.
66289 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
66289 error     bower install
66289 error You can get their info via:
66289 error     npm owner ls MyProject
66289 error There is likely additional logging output above.
66290 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I have my environmental variables setup correctly for Python 2.7, git and npm user profile. My node-gyp is building/rebuilding successfully. Wondering why is this happening ?

Comment: Do you have bower installed, can you run `bower` in in your CLI ?

Comment: This is some issue with git requiring elevated user access aka root/su in linux world. Run your cmd as administrator and try again.

Comment: Yes i am able to run bower in my CLI, ran bower -g install and npm install -g bower, they succeded but failing when the same is being ran as post with npm install. I tried running it with administrator access well, it didn't work. Any other thing i am missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the GIT environment variables. Added the following to environment variables (PATH) , it started working.

```
C:\Users\DemoUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\bin
C:\Users\DemoUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\cmd
```

Make sure to add both \bin and \cmd otherwise it doesn't work with the default \cmd PATH variable git adds automatically during the installation.

Thanks !